# Rearranging rows in MYSQL pivot select

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am trying to do a pivot to get some of the rows as columns.  I have everything working correctly with this statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ',
      year,
      ' then experience_rate end) AS `',
      year, '-Pen`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  spooner_pec order by year asc;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT policy_number, primary_name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM spooner_pec 
                   GROUP BY policy_number');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The only problem is that if the years are out of order in the rows, then they are also out of order as the columns.  Is there any way to rearrange the columns with the select?

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1966c/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `order by year` in `group_concat`:

```
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when year = ',
      year,
      ' then experience_rate end) AS `',
      year, '-Pen`'
    )
    order by year          
  ) into @sql
from
  spooner_pec;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1966c/3)

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't figure out where the heck to put the order by. Will accept when I am able.